# Custom Date Transformation in R

Tags: r

Using R

How do we convert "yyyymm" to "yyyy-mm-01" across all the rows?

Eg: "201603" to "2016-03-01" (ie "yyyy-mm-dd" format)

PS: Here, (dd = 01) is the default date for all 12 months. ie("2016-01-01" , "2016-02-01" , etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `paste` solution:

```
x <- "201603"
paste0(substr(x, 1,4), "-", substr(x, 5,6), "-01")

[1] "2016-03-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transform as date:

```
as.Date(paste0(201603, 01), format = "%Y%m%d")
```

This will create the 2016-03-01 format as the date and not as a character.
If you want to use in all rows on column `Date`

```
data <- data %>%
        mutate(Date = as.Date(paste(Date, 01) format = "%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

additional solution

```
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
x <- c("201603")
ymd(str_c(x,"01"))
[1] "2016-03-01"
```